# Error occur when I start project that using DWR3.0 RC2 with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dwr

I introduce DWR into my project these days. My project is using Spring 4, I was trying to integrate DWR with Spring by using annotation approch. Below are my code for integration work.
An error shown as below occured when I stratup my project on the Tomcat server.

the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrAnnotationPostProcessor.getBeanDefinitionClass(DwrAnnotationPostProcessor.java:96)
at org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(DwrAnnotationPostProcessor.java:52)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPos
Processors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:177)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dwr-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

dwr-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xdfaint.webapp.apps.*.action" />
<dwr:configuration />
<dwr:annotation-config id="dwrAnnotationConfig" />
<dwr:url-mapping />
<dwr:controller id="dwrController" debug="true" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
  <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
    <value>/core/jsp/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

I haven't found any solution yet. Then I try to use Spring 3.2 instead, the startup successed with no error any more. I am not sure if there are problems when Spring 4 meets DWR3. Can any body help? Thx~

---

DWR haven't updated for a long time, and I am not using it anymore. But it is still great helpful that worth to read source codes for studying, like concept of how rest api binding, object operating. About object operating, I found some useful functions like setObject(), was using massively when I did a frontend components encapsulation work. Both setObject function codes and using demo list below, with it I can init a filed in a any nested level of the object, even if there are number of parents object of that new field hasn't been declared yet.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring 4 there is no method `forName` in `ClassUtils` that only accepts String as an argument. As you can see from the JavaDoc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) that method was already deprecated in Spring 3

It seems that DWR has not yet upgraded their code base to support Spring 4. Seems like you'll have to wait for that to happen (although the project seems to be non-active so I wouldn't count on that happening any time soon).

Comment: you are right, I have go into the source of ClassUtils and I found that it has specified two arguments.Dose it mean that DWR3 has to work with Spring 3? Is there any solution about integration Spring4 with DWR3?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to stick will Spring 3 for now. In the event that org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrAnnotationPostProcessor.getBeanDefinitionClass from DWR is calling a method that does not exist in Spring 4, there is nothing you can do I'm afraid if you absolutely need DWR. Please consider accepting the answer so future readers will now it's corrent

Comment: All right. I really need the feature of DWR. I have changed Spring to version 3.2.8. Thanks:)

Comment: After many years, DWR has released a new version that corrects this issue (I tried 3.0.2-RELEASE, which worked for me) -- http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/downloads/#stableRelease .

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the update! Perhaps you would care to add a new answer with this info

Comment: @Dave Thanks, the newest version of DWR which I used  was 3.0.RC3  in that time.